# Einstein Email Open Split Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein

I am trying to create a journey that has an email open likelihood split at the beginning but I am getting an error each time. I am wondering if this is due to there being no email step beforehand, or not enough data to predict.

`Filter defined for activity (Email Open Split) has an issue: There is no Attribute with FullyQualifiedName 'Einstein MC Predictive Scores.Email Open Likelihood'.`

I don't see any information on it really and I've looked at the documentation from salesforce but it doesn't explain this error. Can someone explain it to me and also help me find a way to use it correctly if at all?

Comment: Sounds like a config issue with data model. I would open a support case ideally. If you wanted to check I would validate that in data designer you have a connection to the Einstein data extension "Einstein MC Predictive Scores"

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to data and configuring stuff. What is data designer and how would I check to see that specific data extension?

Comment: All Einstein Engagement Scoring metrics are stored in the Einstein_MC_Predictive_Scores data extension. The system creates this data extension when you provision Einstein Engagement Scoring for your account.
 So may be you check first of this data extension has values in your SFMC account. if not reach out to support and they will investigate further from the back end and will resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a support case and request they reprime the account